# Getting a lot of undefined constants from PHPJasperXML.inc.php when integrating ireport in php

Tags: php, jasper-reports

guys, I'm getting all the following errors when trying to execute my PHP code, I'm trying to integrate report from Jasper with my PHP code:

```
 Notice: Use of undefined constant scaleImage - assumed 'scaleImage' in C:\xampp\htdocs\COMPU_CENTRO\report\PhpJasperLibrary-master\PhpJasperLibrary\PHPJasperXML.inc.php on line 411

 Notice: Undefined variable: imagetype in C:\xampp\htdocs\COMPU_CENTRO\report\PhpJasperLibrary-master\PhpJasperLibrary\PHPJasperXML.inc.php on line 416

 Notice: Undefined property: PHPJasperXML::$gnam in C:\xampp\htdocs\COMPU_CENTRO\report\PhpJasperLibrary-master\PhpJasperLibrary\PHPJasperXML.inc.php on line 581

 Notice: Undefined variable: isPrintRepeatedValues in C:\xampp\htdocs\COMPU_CENTRO\report\PhpJasperLibrary-master\PhpJasperLibrary\PHPJasperXML.inc.php on line 600

 Notice: Undefined property: PHPJasperXML::$gnam in C:\xampp\htdocs\COMPU_CENTRO\report\PhpJasperLibrary-master\PhpJasperLibrary\PHPJasperXML.inc.php on line 581

 Notice: Undefined variable: isPrintRepeatedValues in C:\xampp\htdocs\COMPU_CENTRO\report\PhpJasperLibrary-master\PhpJasperLibrary\PHPJasperXML.inc.php on line 600

 Notice: Undefined property: PHPJasperXML::$gnam in C:\xampp\htdocs\COMPU_CENTRO\report\PhpJasperLibrary-master\PhpJasperLibrary\PHPJasperXML.inc.php on line 581

 Notice: Undefined variable: isPrintRepeatedValues in C:\xampp\htdocs\COMPU_CENTRO\report\PhpJasperLibrary-master\PhpJasperLibrary\PHPJasperXML.inc.php on line 600

 Notice: Undefined property: PHPJasperXML::$gnam in C:\xampp\htdocs\COMPU_CENTRO\report\PhpJasperLibrary-master\PhpJasperLibrary\PHPJasperXML.inc.php on line 581

 Notice: Undefined variable: isPrintRepeatedValues in C:\xampp\htdocs\COMPU_CENTRO\report\PhpJasperLibrary-master\PhpJasperLibrary\PHPJasperXML.inc.php on line 600

 Notice: Undefined property: PHPJasperXML::$gnam in C:\xampp\htdocs\COMPU_CENTRO\report\PhpJasperLibrary-master\PhpJasperLibrary\PHPJasperXML.inc.php on line 581

 Notice: Undefined variable: isPrintRepeatedValues in C:\xampp\htdocs\COMPU_CENTRO\report\PhpJasperLibrary-master\PhpJasperLibrary\PHPJasperXML.inc.php on line 600

 Notice: Undefined property: PHPJasperXML::$gnam in C:\xampp\htdocs\COMPU_CENTRO\report\PhpJasperLibrary-master\PhpJasperLibrary\PHPJasperXML.inc.php on line 581

 Notice: Undefined variable: isPrintRepeatedValues in C:\xampp\htdocs\COMPU_CENTRO\report\PhpJasperLibrary-master\PhpJasperLibrary\PHPJasperXML.inc.php on line 600
```

**My folder distribution:**

[image: My folder distribution]

`COMPU_CENTRO` is the folder of the app the screen of the report is inside that folder.

This is the include `report_view` of Jaspersoft

```
<?php

  //Import the PhpJasperLibrary
  include_once("report/PhpJasperLibrary-master/PhpJasperLibrary/tcpdf/tcpdf.php");
  include_once("report/PhpJasperLibrary-master/PhpJasperLibrary/PHPJasperXML.inc.php");

  //database connection details
  $server = "127.0.0.1";
  $db = "db_compu";
  $user = "root";
  $pass = "";
  $version = "0.8b"; // User for Mysql
  $pgport = 3306;
  $pchartfolder = "./class/pchart2";

  //display errors should be off in the php.ini file
  //ini_set(‘display_errors’, 0);

  //setting the path to the created jrxml file
  $xml =  simplexml_load_file("report/report1.jrxml");
  $PHPJasperXML = new PHPJasperXML();
  //$PHPJasperXML->debugsql=true;
  //$PHPJasperXML->arrayParameter=array("parameter1″=>1);
  $PHPJasperXML->xml_dismantle($xml);

  //Mysql
  $PHPJasperXML->transferDBtoArray($server,$user,$pass,$db); // Mysql Default

  //Oracle
  //$odbc_name=’screen’;

  // For using Oracle , DSN create  First
  //$PHPJasperXML->transferDBtoArray($server,$user,$pass,$odbc_name,’ODBC’);//
  //$PHPJasperXML->outpage("I");    //page output method I:standard output, D:Download file
?>
```

**How can I fix this error?**

Comment: Hi Pablo. Welcome to StackOverflow! To make your question easier for others to understand and help you, could you please provide any relevant code and a detailed explanation of what you are trying to achieve, what you are trying that's failing and what you're expecting to happen.

Comment: Hey, I feel this is a well-written question but is a bit too broad and has too many questions loaded into it. I would try to reduce the scope of how many errors you are trying to fix in a single question.

Comment: Hey Guys thanks for your help i will edit and make it easier to read